# nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting errors when porting this map into Objective C.

```
typedef map<uint32_t,string>EventMapType;
EventMapType cEventMap;
```

error: nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<' token

error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'uint32_t'

error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'string'

error: expected ';' before 'cEventMap'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compile the source as objective-c++ (use mm extension)

Comment: Is there any other equivalent declaration to do the above functionality in Objective C. I have written some of the classes in Objective C.I have declared this class alone in Objective c++. But still i'm getting errors.

Comment: @ron No, there isn't. The above code isn't C, it's C++, and therefore warrants you use Objective-C++. What are the other errors you're getting? And have you considered using a data structure other than a map for your needs? Like an `NSDictionary`?